# Manual python zip() function. How to end this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making my own zip() function in python rn. I'm stuck when i want to automate iterables number.
Here is my code:

```
    def myzip(*iterables):
       new_list = []
       x = len(iterables)
       n = len(iterables[0])
       for i in range(n):
          new_list.append((iterables[0][i], iterables[1][i], iterables[2][i]))
       return new_list    
    myzip([1,2,3,4], 'afhj',[1,2,3,4])
```

So output here is good:  [(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'f', 2), (3, 'h', 3), (4, 'j', 4)].
But what i want to do is to automate this line:

```
    new_list.append((iterables[0][i], iterables[1][i], iterables[2][i]))
```

Because i don't want to specify each iterable.
How to do that?

Comment: Please be aware that iterables do not have a length and are not indexable. ``myzip`` would not work with, say, generators.

Comment: Also, you assume that the first iterable is the shortest one.

Comment: Yeah, for this exercise i assumed that all of the iterables have the same amount of elements. Thanks for this reminder @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) doc provides an implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
new_item = tuple(iterable[i] for iterable in iterables)
new_list.append(new_item)
```

instead of

```py
new_list.append((iterables[0][i], iterables[1][i], iterables[2][i]))
```

This is like a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but it creates a tuple.

As @MisterMiyagi has commented, please be aware that `myzip` does not handle iterables. Your function would handle sequences, including lists, tuples, and strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have a variable number of iterables, you'll need to process all of them (not just the first 3) so you should use list comprehensions to manipulate them.

You should also implement your function as a generator so that you don't build a huge resulting list with all the combined values before returning to the caller.

Here's an example:

```
def myZip(*iterables):
    iterables = [*map(iter,iterables)] # convert parameters to iterators
    Done   = object()                  # end of iteration flag
    while True:
       zipped = tuple(next(i,Done) for i in iterables) # advance all iterators
       if Done in zipped: break                        # stop when one is done
       yield zipped                                    # return combinations
```

output:

```
print(*myZip([1,2,3],"abcd","xyz"))

(1, 'a', 'x') (2, 'b', 'y') (3, 'c', 'z')
```

If you rely on the lengths of your parameters, you shouldn't call them iterables because the function will be limited to indexable collections/arrays (lists,ranges,tuples). It will not support actual iterables (such as generators, comprehensions, etc.).

```
def myZip(*array):
    result = []
    for i in range(min(map(len,array))):    # index range (shortest)
        zipped = tuple(a[i] for a in array) # combine arrays at index
        result.append(zipped) # build list of zipped tuples
    return result
```

Comment: Nicely done for iterables. However `myZip()` enters into an infinite loop without argument unlike the original `zip()`. I suggest adding a check on `iterables` or using `while iterables`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more efficient generator avoiding the need to use a sentinel object:

```py
def myZip(*iterables):
    iterables = list(map(iter, iterables))
    while iterables:
        curr_tuple = tuple(map(next, iterables))
        if not curr_tuple:
            return
        yield curr_tuple
```

Since Python 3.8, it can even be shortened as follows:

```py
def myZip(*iterables):
    iterables = list(map(iter, iterables))
    while curr_tuple := tuple(map(next, iterables)):
        yield curr_tuple
```